# Segmented control differenciate buttons

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to create a new OS X application. I've got a table view where information should be displayed, underneath it there is a Segmented Control section with two buttons (+ and -).

[image]

I used this code to show up a dialog / modal:

```
@IBAction func addDevices(_ sender: NSSegmentedControl) {

      let index = sender.selectedSegment

    let controller = (self.view.window?.windowController as! MainWindowController)

    controller.createNewDevices(sender)

    print("works")
}
```

**How can I differentiate between + button and - button pressed?** At the moment, both buttons call up my dialog.

Thanks for your attention, I hope someone can help me!

P.S.: New to Stack, if I didn't post as you expected it, please let me know what I can do better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selectedSegment property.

```
var selectedSegment: Int
```

The index of the selected segment of the control, or -1 if no segment is selected.

Button "+" have index 0, and "-" have index 1.

You can do that:

```
switch sender.selectedSegment {
   case 0: // do actions if "+"
   case 1: // do actions if "-"
   default: print("No actions for this button")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. This works perfect. For other people, my code now looks like this:

Comment: I'm glad to help you ;]